# Bootstrap dropdowns behaving differently

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, bootstrap-5

Please see here: http://www.proalliance.com.mx/2021/about.html  I have two dropdown sections in the navigation.

For About, it behaves as I'd like, dropping down on hover. But for Insurance, it needs to be clicked to drop down. I can't figure out where this behavior is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your javascript code contained in **script.js** is wrong.
There is this code:

```
// On hover
const dropdownCheck = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

if (dropdownCheck !== null) { 
    document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("mouseleave", toggleDropdown);
    document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("mouseover", toggleDropdown);

    // On click
    document.querySelector(".dropdown").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
```

and in that script you are using *document.querySelector*.
Based in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) of that method, it says:

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within
> the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
> selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

So, your code in **script.js** is only selecting the first *.dropdown* element, not all of them, and for this reason only run in your *"About Us"* first dropdown menu element.

In order to fix this you should recode your **script.js** file and try to use *querySelectorAll* instead *querySelector*.
You will find more information about how to use *querySelectorAll* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Aha!! Ok, I'll do that, thanks a million!